Flutter app image selection with custom UI
Creating a travel journal and users can upload images to their entries.  Running into a headache with implementing image selection.  Tried the image_picker package but had issues with limiting the number of selection and it shows photo edits on android that causes app to crash.
Implemented my own custom UI using photo_manager package but want access to cloud storage like you get with the system picker so it shows both in the list.  Been looking forever for either a package to do it, or a way to incorporate the google photos api into my local storage but have had issues.  Any help pointing in a possible direction would be appreciated.

